# Struggling to understand css formatting

Tags: html, css

I'm having a rough go at understanding some properties of css. I've been working on a website for the last few weeks and as a whole I've been able to do what I've been trying to do, but the footers/headers etc. seem to be the most unintuitive part of all of it

This is somewhat what I'm going for

https://jsfiddle.net/ekv62gha/99/

But you can see the footer overlaps the body content. I can add more margin, but overall it seems like there's something fundamentally wrong with my approach. The main things I'm trying to do:

1. Push the footer to the bottom when I add content to the body
2. Keep the footer at the bottom even when there's no content in the body

and later on, I have an "audio player" which is basically just another div/row that takes 100% of the width of the screen. I'm putting it inside of the body, and I would like for it to be fixed at the bottom of the page until the user scrolls down, at which point I want it to "stick" to the bottom of the body (but not overlap or the footer and the footer should still be at the bottom of the page)

There also shouldnt be margin between the audio player and the footer

I was able to accomplish #1 and #3 successfully, but then number 2 failed. Then i went back and tried to fix it and everything just went completely haywire

```
<div class="fullContainer">
  <header class="siteHeader">
    Header Content
  </header>
   <div class="bodyContainer">
   <span>adding content</span><span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span>
  </div>
  <footer class="siteFooter">
    Footer content
  </footer>
</div>
```

> ```
> .fullContainer {
>   min-height: 100vh;
>   position: relative;
>   background-color: blue;
>   display: flex;
>   align-items: center;
>   justify-content: center;
>   flex-direction: column;
> }
>
> .bodyContainer {
>   display: flex;
>   flex-direction: column;
>   justify-content: center;
>   align-items: center;
>   min-height: 80vh;
>   background-color: red;
>   width: 100%;
>   position: relative;
> }
>
> .siteFooter {
>   height: 10vh;
>   padding: 2vh, 0, 2vh, 0;
>   background-color: black;
>   width: 100%;
>   bottom: 0;
>   position: absolute;
> }
>
> .siteHeader {
>   width: 100%;
>   height: 10vh;
>   position: absolute;
>   top: 0;
>   background-color: black;
> }
> ```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant code in an [mre]. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar). A listing of CSS is almost meaningless without the HTML on which it acts.

Comment: Are you trying to keep your footer at the bottom regardless of whether there is content past the bottom fold or not or whether or not there is enough content to fully cover the view port?

Comment: The footer should always be the very last thing in the flow, but the user needs to scroll down past all of the content to see it. Unless there's no content, at which point I want the body to be completely empty but still keep the footer visible at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try change the vh in the footer and head to em or rem and maybe px, because when you try it in smaller screens the height and sometimes the width can get messy.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this… you may change the CSS styles to meet your needs.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1330px;
}

body {
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-family: calibri;
  color: black;
  min-height: 93%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 98.8%;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  background: #4DB5E7;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 80px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Footer */

.bottom_margin {
  height: 1em;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E4FBFE;
  font-size: 8pt;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bodyContainer {
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="bodyContainer">
  <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span>
  <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span>
  <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span>
  <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span>
  <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span>
  <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span>
  <span>adding content</span> <span>adding content</span>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer is working Great</div>
```